# Why Image Header not letting me save image?

Tags: php, header

i am using jcrop to make crop of images.
but the resulting croped image is not save able, i mean when i right click and save image, it saves the .php file instead.
Here is the code used:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
$targ_iw = $_REQUEST['iwidth'];
$targ_ih = $_REQUEST['iheight'];
$source = $_REQUEST['tname'];
if(empty($targ_iw)){
    $targ_iw = $_POST['w'];
    $targ_ih = $_POST['h'];
    }
    $jpeg_quality = 90;

    $src = 'http://www.imageopti.com/crop/files/'.$source;
    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_iw, $targ_ih );

    imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
    $targ_iw,$targ_ih,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($dst_r, null, $jpeg_quality);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: And what's inside php file?

Comment: Top php code mentioned above, below is the html/jquery form which is sending data to this part to create crop.

Comment: No, I meant - have you tried to open the saved php file?

Comment: just did, it looks like jibberish by that i mean image code written in php file.. as i see

Comment: what if you just rename the downloaded file to .jpg? I'm wondered that a programmer doesn't know that extension is used only for determining what program to use for opening the file (in some popular OS).

Answer (score 1):

- In your HTML code, add

  ```
  <input type="hidden" name="create" value="true" />
  ```
- Add my function

  ```
  function new_my_resampled($source, $iwidth, $iheight, $w, $h, $x, $y)
  {
      $filename   = "http://www.imageopti.com/crop/files/" . $source;

      $targ_iw = $iwidth;
      $targ_ih = $iheight;
      if(empty($targ_iw))
      {
          $targ_iw = $w;
          $targ_ih = $h;
      }

      $image = imagecreatetruecolor($targ_iw,$targ_ih);
      $o_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
      imagecopyresampled($image,$o_img,0,0,$x,$y,$targ_iw,$targ_ih,$w,$h);
      imagejpeg($image, null, 100);
  }
  ```
- In your php file add

  ```
  if($_POST['create'] == 'true')
  {
      /*
       * Write here your conditions
       */

      $filename = "http://www.imageopti.com/crop/files/" . $_POST['tname'];
      $f_name   = trim(basename($filename));
      //$f_size   = getSizeFile($filename);
      header("(anti-spam-content-type:) image/jpeg");
      header('Cache-control: max-age=31536000');
      header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', (time() + 31536000)) . ' GMT');
      header('Content-transfer-encoding: binary');
      header('ETag: "' . time() . '"');
      header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $f_name);
      header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
      header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
      header("Content-Type: application/download");
      header("Content-Description: File Transfer");  
      //header("Content-length:" . $f_size);
      header("Cache-control: private"); 
      new_my_resampled($_POST['tname'], $_POST['iwidth'], $_POST['iheight'], $_POST['w'], $_POST['h'],$_POST['x'],$_POST['y']);
  }
  ```
- !!! If you want to use `$f_zise` and `header("Content-length:" . $f_size);` you can use this function `getSizeFile` from [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php#84130)

Please test it ...

Comment: Stil problem persists. Try it your self. here : http://www.imageopti.com/index_crop.php?name=1361661584.jpg

Comment: i also implemented something similar to make move generated thumbnail in a different category. and display it. but that's not what i am looking for. i wanted proper headers so image could be saveable. this will give me the hastle of bulking up thumbnails in a directory which won't be used again.

Comment: I tested my modifications, but I haven't enough reputation to post an image ... Please tell me (after your test) if it is what do you want ..